# how to remove rows whose not have values?

Tags: pyspark

I am removing some words from a column. at the end of the day some rows will be empty becouse all their string has been removed. there might be space or whitespace or nothing. How I can remove these rows?

I tried this but for some reason it does not work for all kind of rows:

```
df = df.withColumn('col1',trim(regexp_replace('col1','\n',''))) 
df=df.filter(df.col1!='')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the filter you've applied will work for blanks, but not if it has whitespaces.

try `trim(<column>) != ''`.

Example

```py
spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('',), (' ',), ('  ',)]).toDF(['foo']). \
    filter(func.col('foo') != ''). \
    count()
# 2

spark.sparkContext.parallelize([('',), (' ',), ('  ',)]).toDF(['foo']). \
    filter(func.trim(func.col('foo')) != ''). \
    count()
# 0
```